# Keras(Tensorflow) LSTM error in spyder and jupyter

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda, lstm

when I use google colab, there's no error in code

but when I use spyder or jupyter, the error occurs.

```
Model_10 = Sequential()
Model_10.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape = (1,10,5), stateful = True))
Model_10.add(Dense(5, activation = 'linear'))

Model_10.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')

Model_10.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2, shuffle=False, callbacks=[history])
```

x_train_data.shape = (260,10,5)

y_train_data.shape = (260,1,5)

I'm using python3.7 and tensorflow 2.0
I don't know why error occurs in anaconda only.

ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ

error code

ValueError: A target array with shape (260, 1, 5) was passed for an output of shape (1, 5) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should reshape your labels/targets:

```
y_train_data = y_train_data.reshape((260,5))
```

Since you're using `batch_input_shape` in the input layer and specifying batch size of 1, the model will take one example from your labels at each step which will have a shape of (1, 5) for the labels anyway.

Comment: then, when i do it in colab why it works? just difference in version tensorflow 2.2.0 , 2.0.0 ??

Comment: You can create and compile the model on colab, it won't give any error. You can train such a model, giving appropriate input data. The error is when you try to train, or fit the model and give your data as you explained. Do you call model.fit on colab?